# Why can't i rebase a merged topic branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Say, I have this situation in my git repo

```
A--B--C--D   master
|\
| E--F       topic
|
 \
  G--H       other
```

and I want to rebase `topic` to the `other` branch. This works fine with:

```
git rebase --onto other master topic
```

which gives me

```
A--B--C--D   master
|
 \
  G--H       other
      \
       E--F  topic
```

But if `topic` was already merged into master (`git merge topic`) the above `rebase` command doesn't work anymore. If I try it, I seem to get something like this:

```
A--B--C--D--M  master
|\        /
| E--F----
|
 \
  G--H         other / topic
```

whereas I wanted this:

```
A--B--C--D--M  master
|\        /
| E--F----
|
 \
  G--H         other
      \
       E'--F'  topic
```

Why is this and how can I rebase `topic` onto `other` even if it was already merged to `master`?

EDIT: Updated bottom diagram to make clear, that `E` and `F` are not identical commits - but introduce the same changeset.

EDIT 2: What I really want is, as if i first created a copy of `topic` (say `topic-rebased`) that I rebase to `other` *before* I then merge `topic` into `other`:

```
git checkout topic
git checkout -b topic-rebased
git rebase --onto other master topic-rebased
git checkout master
git merge topic
```

This works fine. But the rebase doesn't work anymore if topic was already merged into `master`.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t expect two of each `E` and `F` commits to exist within your repository. If they have different parents (which they do: One set has `A` as parent, the other has `H` as parent), then one `E` will be a different `E` than the other.

In your case, if you want this result, you should look into [cherry-picking](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

```
git checkout topic   # puts you on `H`
git cherry-pick E
git cherry-pick F
```

This will apply the commits `E` and `F` into your current branch and essentially create copies of it. So you should end up with the desired result.

Comment: Ok, well I've updated the question a little. What if cherry picking is not an option, because there are 100s of commits on `topic` that i also need on `other`? See EDIT 2 above, for what I really want.

Comment: I don’t really understand your edit, but if you need to cherry pick many commits (i.e. there are many more commits between E and F), you can also just cherry-pick a range. For example on `other` use `git cherry-pick A..topic` to cherry-pick all commits that were introduced by topic.

Comment: Ok, but then I need to manually find out, where to start and where to end. Not sure, what is unclear about my edit. The lower example should make it quite clear: It works if I rebase *before* I merge the topic branch. It doesn't work anymore if i try to rebase after topic was merged.

Comment: Cherry-pick and rebase both rewrite history by creating new commits.  There are times when cherry-picking ranges makes more sense than rebasing, although I think in this instance rebasing is the better choice (as it obviates the need to manually determine the commits to copy over).

Answer (score 0):

If your history is as in your example, this will do it:

```
git checkout topic
git rebase --onto other --root
```

I gave this a shot to confirm:

```
% git init .
(add commit a)
% touch a; git add a ; git commit -m "a"
% git checkout -b topic
(add commits e and f, elided for brevity)
% ls
a e f
% git checkout master
% git checkout -b other
(add commits g and h)
% ls
a g h
% git checkout master
(add commits b, c, and d)
% ls
a b c d
% git merge topic
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 e | 0
 f | 0
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
% ls
a b c d e f
% git checkout topic
% ls
a e f
% git rebase --onto other --root
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: e
Applying: f
% ls
a e f g h
```

It'll automatically find the shared parent and add (cherry-pick, really) only the commits from the topic branch, even if it's already merged into master.